# fields and base_fields - Django

Tags: django, django-admin

When creating a flatpage, I want the user to select a template from a predefined list. In order to keep the `Flatpage` model untouched, I prefer `ChoiceField` over `ModelChoiceField` (the latter provides the PK of the template, but I need the name for the template_name field):

```
class NewFlatpageForm(FlatpageForm):

    template_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.base_fields['template_name'].choices = ProjectTemplate.objects.values_list('path', 'name')
        super(NewFlatpageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I override `__init__` or Django populates choices at server start and does not update the list then.

I don't have any admin experience, but I did similar things using the `fields` attribute when not using admin. However in this case, I got an exception telling `fields` is not an attribute of the form. `__dict__` showed me there's a `base_fields` attribute and using it works. So, why use base_fields here, and why is `fields` not present and finally am I doing something hacky?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`fields` doesn't exist until **after** you've called `super`. So just swap the order of the lines, so that `super` comes first.

Answer (score 16):

A lesson from my own experience: modifying `base_fields` means that your modifications stick around "forever" (until python exits).  In your case, that's probably not a problem, as you are always using the same field name, and you are replacing its values with the assignment from ProjectTemplate...

In my case, I wanted completely different fields based on parameters in the constructor. Since my field names were usually different, each time I instantiated a form, I added new fields but didn't eliminate the ones from the last time.

By calling `super` early (as indicated here) and then making my dynamic changes to `self.fields` instead of `self.base_fields`, I was able to eliminate the problem of an ever growing list of fields.  It makes perfect sense now, but I wasn't familiar with all of the syntax details and was hacking through instead of trying to understand it first.

Comment: Also see [warning in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form): *"Beware not to alter the `base_fields` attribute ..."*

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Joe Germuska. If you truly need to change the form based on the request, you can use a deepcopy to make sure nothing is changed by reference:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ResourceAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form = copy.deepcopy(form)

    if obj:
        form.base_fields['email'] = EmailField(initial=obj.user.email)
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        form.base_fields['user'].widget = HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'hide_form_row'})

    return form
```