# How do I get the actual object id in a Django admin page (inside formfield_for_foreignkey)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I 've already solved the problem of getting the object id being edited using this code:

```
class CompanyUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """
    Defines tabular rules for editing company users direct in company admin
    """
    model = CompanyUser

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

        if db_field.name == "user":
            users = User.objects.filter( Q(is_superuser=False) )
            query = Q()
            for u in users:
                aux = CompanyUser.objects.filter(user=u)
                if aux.count() == 0:
                    query |= Q(pk=u.id)

            try:
                cpu = CompanyUser.objects.filter(company__id=int(request.path.split('/')[4]))
                for p in cpu:
                    query |= Q(pk=p.user.id)
            except:
                pass

            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(query).order_by('username')

        return super(CompanyUserInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

But, the *int(request.path.split('/')[4])* is really ugly. I want to know how I get the id from the Django AdminModel. I'm sure it's somewhere inside it, anyone knows?

Thank you in advance! ;D

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/949268

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as i know it is not possible to access the current instance through the `formfield_for_...`-methods, because they will only be called for a single field instance!

A better point to hook into this logic where you can access the whole instance/form would be `get_form`. You can also overwrite a form field's queryset there!

Comment: Where do I find some docs about the get_form?
I tried to get the object through it and it worked, but I have no idea of how to use the method to overwrite the form field's queryset there... =/

Comment: See the original code at http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py. If `form` would be the form returned by the orignal `get_form` method, `form.base_fields` should be a dictionary of the field objects!

Comment: Ok! Thank you man! I'll take a look on it and post here the solution. If I achieve it! Thank you again! ;D

Answer (score 29):

After some digging around, we were able to grab the arguments that get passed to the admin view (after being parsed by django admin's urls.py) and use that (self_pub_id) to grab the object:

```
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "authors":
            #this line below got the proper primary key for our object of interest
            self_pub_id = request.resolver_match.args[0]

            #then we did some stuff you don't care about
            pub = Publication.objects.get(id=self_pub_id)
            kwargs["queryset"] = pub.authors.all()
        return super(PublicationAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

A more elegant solution is to use the accepted answers recomendation and leverage the get_form ModelAdmin member function. Like so:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    my_id_for_formfield = None
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            self.my_id_for_formfield = obj.id
        return super(ProfileAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "person":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Person.objects.filter(profile=self.my_id_for_formfield)
        return super(ProfileAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey self, this is hacky!! But it works. We cross our own path again.

Comment: You can event store the whole object, no need to only store the id. Nice solution, though!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me some hours, 
Actually for me, django 2.2.5 that was at 
request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id', None)

Answer (score 19):

The following code snippet will give you the object id:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs['object_id']
```

Sample usage: (I'm filtering the phone numbers shown, to only show customer's phone numbers)

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'preferred_contact_number':
        kwargs['queryset'] = CustomerPhone.objects.filter(customer__pk=request.resolver_match.kwargs['object_id'])
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

P.S: Found it by debugging and walking through accessible variables.

Comment: This is the best way to go !

Answer (score 4):

I made it work by rewrite `change_view()`

```
class CartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    self.object_id = object_id
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)


def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    print self.object_id
    return super(CartAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

then you can call `self.object_id` inside `formfield_for_foreignkey()`

Comment: It worked fine for me, but if after making a modification the value is still high, to reset it you have to do the same in add_view and set the value of self.object_id = None

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

If you *really* need the object `id` inside `formfield_for_foreignkey()`, you could use `request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id')` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match)), as proposed in [@mazyar-mk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564228).

But, if the *goal* is e.g. to filter a field queryset based on the object being edited, it is probably better to either

- extend `ModelForm.__init__()`, as suggested in the [documentation for `formfield_for_foreignkey()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), or
- extend `ModelAdmin.get_form()`, overriding the form class's `base_fields`.

See examples below.

### Long answer (with example)

The accepted [answer by @BernhardVallant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618313) suggests extending [`ModelAdmin.get_form()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form), and in the comments it is [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618085/how-do-i-get-the-actual-object-id-in-a-django-admin-page-inside-formfield-for-f#comment5100121_4618313) to modify the `base_fields` attribute. (Note that `get_form()` returns a form *class*, not a bound form.)

This is tempting, and you can probably get away with something like this:

```py
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
    form_class = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
    if obj:
        form_class.base_fields['my_field'].queryset = my_queryset.filter(
            my_lookup=obj
        )
    return form_class
```

Note that Django's documentation for the [Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form) warns against modifying `base_fields` (also see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4403765)):

> Beware not to alter the `base_fields` attribute because this modification will influence all subsequent `ContactForm` instances within the same Python process: ...

However, I do not think this restriction applies here, because the admin form is generated dynamically, [using a `modelform_factory`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d22ba0763086f71fb6df8502162ea63944d166b1/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L835).

The [answer by @fizxmike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27304574) provides an alternative example using `get_form()` without modifying `base_fields`, but it still needs `formfield_for_foreignkey()` as well.

#### Solution from documentation

The [documentation for `formfield_for_foreignkey()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) suggests another approach altogether (also see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21528) and [fields docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships)):

> For more complex filters, you can use [the] `ModelForm.__init__()` method to filter based on an `instance` of your model ...

Once the form is initialized, you can access the `fields` attribute to modify the queryset. Moreover, you get access to the actual object (as `self.instance`), not just the object id.

For example:

```py
class MyModelAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk is not None:
            self.fields['my_field'].queryset = my_queryset.filter(
                my_lookup=self.instance
            )


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    ...
```

Here we check `self.instance.pk` to see if the object exists in the database (add vs change view).

This approach also works with inlines.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach could be writing an helper method to obtain the model instance (if any), much as you normally do with a (bounded) ModelForm, and from that retrieve the id or any other property:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_instance(self, request):
        try:
            object_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs['object_id']
            obj = self.get_object(request, object_id)
        except:
            obj = None
        return obj
```

Answer (score -2):

I was dealing with a similar situation, and realized that the id that that I needed from the request, I could from from the model it self since it was a foreign key to that model. So it would be something like:

```
cpu = CompanyUser.objects.filter(company__id=self.company_id)
```

or what ever the structure of your model dictates.

Comment: Could you please add some more context and explanation to this answer.  What method does this line go in? What class? Which module?

Answer (score -2):

I made it work by creating a property() in model.py that returns the ID

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    ...
    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
    getid = property(get_id)
```

admin.py:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['mylink',]
    def mylink(self, object):
        return '<a href="http://mywebsite/'+object.getid+'/">Edit</a>'
    mylink.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: That is easy. I wanted a way to use the id in formfield_for_foreignkey, not to simply show it to the user.

Comment: Agreed, this does not answer the question.