# django admin: show list of items filtered

Tags: python, django

Am working on a django admin interface and I have a model which has a foreign key. In that field, am getting a drop down menu when the admin pages are viewed. Is there a way to filter the drop down result only where is_active=1 for example?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[limit_choices_to](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) is what you are after.

If you only want the limited selection in your `ModelAdmin` you should tweak your `ModelForm` accordingly.

Something like this should do it:

```
class YourAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = self.fields['your_fk_field'].queryset
        self.fields['your_fk_field'].queryset = qs.filter(is_active=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(is_active=1)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

If you need access to current object check this [How do I get the actual object id in a Django admin page (inside formfield_for_foreignkey)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4618085/2207154)