# How to restrict foreign key objects for autocomplete search results in django ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields?

Tags: django, django-admin

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29455444), I was able to filter foreign keys choices to select:

[image]

But when I mark spm as autocomplete_field:`autocomplete_fields = ['spm']`, the spm field becomes from select field to autocomplete search field:
[image]

But the foreign key choices are not restricted as configured in "formfield_for_foreignkey" any more.

Even when I am attaching the widget inside formfield_for_foreignkey method, spm autocomplete options are getting restricted:

```
@admin.register(CustomModel)
class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    #autocomplete_fields = ['spm']
    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        request.current_object = obj
        return super(CustomModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):

        if db_field.name == 'spm':
            instance = request.current_object
            if instance.brand and instance.memory_size:
                    filtered_qs=StandardProductWithMemorySize.objects.filter(
                        product__brand=instance.brand,
                        memory_size=instance.memory_size
                    )
                    kwargs['queryset'] = filtered_qs
                    db = kwargs.get('using')
                    kwargs['widget'] = AutocompleteSelect(db_field.remote_field, self.admin_site)
        return super(
            CustomModelAdmin, self
        ).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter choices in Django2's autocomplete\_fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152908/how-to-filter-choices-in-django2s-autocomplete-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `autocomplete_fields = ['spm']`, overriding `change_form.html` template and using JavaScript to make HTML select element searchable(with auto-completion) worked for me:

[image]

content of `change_form.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#id_spm").select2({});
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

The HTML select element on which `select2` function operate:

```
<select name="spm" required="" id="id_spm" >
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
  <option value="67688">apple iphone 7</option>
  <option value="69093">apple iphone 7 plus</option>
  <option value="71453">apple ipad pro</option>
  <option value="71076">apple ipad pro 9.7</option>
  <option value="34840">apple ipad pro 10.5</option>
  <option value="72303">apple iphone 8 plus</option>
  <option value="72301">apple iphone 8</option>
  <option value="72307">apple iphone x</option>
  <option value="71243">apple ipad pro 12.9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Butchering the template and hardcoding is not a great answer.

Comment: This is the easiest solution I have found... all other ones are overly complex

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Django, unfortunately still unresolved at the time of this writing:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29707

Comment: And still not fixed three years later....