How to change/filter option list in TreeNodeChoiceField in a TabularInline
How to change the option/choice list of conto field, based on value gruppo_id?
conto is a ForeignKey to a branch of a tree described as model.ContoCOGE(MPTTModel).
For each gruppo there is a tree, which develops to a certain depth.
How to filter among all the trees and, in TreeNodeChoiceField in a TablularInline, to list only that with a group_id?
In debug, formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs) overriden returns the correct tree. But the browser renders the page with the select field with all the trees.
#model.py
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from multigroup.models import Gruppo

class ContoCOGE (MPTTModel):  
    gruppo = models.ForeignKey(Gruppo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='contoCOCGE_gruppo')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class PncGen (models.Model):
    gruppo = models.ForeignKey(Gruppo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other stuff

class PncRighe (models.Model):
    gruppo = models.ForeignKey(Gruppo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idPnc = models.ForeignKey(PncGen,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #puntatore alla testata
    conto = models.ForeignKey(ContoCOGE,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    #other stuff


#admin.py
from django_mptt_admin.admin import DjangoMpttAdmin

class PncRigheInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PncRighe
    autocomplete_fields = ['partitarioRiga','conto']
    extra = 1

    def filter_tree_queryset(self, queryset,request):
        qs = queryset.filter(gruppo_id=int(request.session['gruppo_utente']))
        return qs

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'gruppo': int(request.session['gruppo_utente'])}

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'gruppo' or db_field.name == 'idRiga' or db_field.name == 'idPnc':
            kwargs['widget'] = forms.HiddenInput()

        if db_field.name == 'conto':
            
            db = kwargs.get("using")
            qs = self.get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
            kwargs['queryset']=qs.filter(gruppo_id = request.session['gruppo_utente'] )

@admin.register(PncGen)
class PncGenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #...
    inlines = (PncRigheInline,)


I tried a full solution reading, without success.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48152908/3881829

I found a quasi-solution. It works, but without autocomplete feature.
I can change the queryset of a ForeignKeyField using formfield_for_foreignkey, but combining with autocomplete doesn't work.
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'gruppo' or db_field.name == 'idRiga' or db_field.name == 'idPnc':
            kwargs['widget'] = forms.HiddenInput()

        if db_field.name == 'conto':
            db = kwargs.get("using")
            qs = self.get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
            db_field.choices = [ ( p.id, '{0}'.format( str(p)),) for p in qs.filter(gruppo_id = request.session['gruppo_utente']).exclude(parent=None) ]

        return super(PncRigheInline,self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

