# base_field initial value is not setting from _init_ function

Tags: python, django

Have a look at this question [fields and base_fields - Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140862/fields-and-base-fields-django). I want to do the exact stuff, except I need to set the initial for this field instead of choice. Even I have **swap the order of lines also** as mentioned in the answer of that question, but I am not getting the initial set value at frond end.  mean while when I tried to check the code with `pdb`, I was getting no error and value also set to 5 successfully

```
class NewFlatpageForm(FlatpageForm):
        template_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [])
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(NewFlatpageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.base_fields['template_name'].initial = 5
```

Comment: Why do you have to do this in the init method? Why not just in the field definition (`ChoiceField(initial=5)`)?

Comment: This 5 is only for the question , I am setting a variable to it basically whose value I am getting from init function only

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `super` call goes first in your `__init__` method, then modify the field's initial value in `self.fields`, not `self.base_fields`.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(NewFlatpageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['template_name'].initial = 5
```